# Re-enter USA for F-1 student

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, f1-visas

I am currently a graduate student studying in the United States and traveled outside the country for the winter break. I will doing an internship in the spring 2020 semester and have been issued a new I-20 with the CPT - work authorization, for the same.

However, it was approved when I was outside the country, and hence I do not have the new document with me. But I have the original F1 I-20 with the required travel signature with me.

Does anyone know if this would suffice at immigration while re-entering the country or do I need the new I-20 which has the CPT?